# Gerald Folland Exercise 3.4.22 - Wording of the Question?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

The exercise reads as follows:

> **22.** If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n),\ f\neq0$, there exist $C,R>0$ such that $Hf(x)\geq C|x|^{-n}$ for $|x|>R$.

My confusion: What are the initial conditions exactly? As far as I can tell, the conditions on function $f$ are that it is in $L^1$ and not equal to zero...however, if these are the correct initial conditions, how would function such as $\chi_{\{a\}}$ not serve as a contradiction? In particular, we know that $H\chi_{\{a\}}(x)=\sup_{r>0}(A_r\chi_{\{a\}}(x))=0$ for all $x\neq a$.

(p.s., please don't give an answer to the exercise. I would prefer not to be tempted. Thank you!)

---

Edit: $Hf(x)$ refers to Hardy-Littlewood's maximal function. I have replied with the definition of such function according to Folland.

Comment: So, what does $H$ stand for? My guess would be Hardy-Littlewood's maximal function but more context would be good

Comment: @FShrike Yes, Hardy-Littlewood's maximal function! Sorry, I should've specified. Folland defines it $Hf(x)=\sup_{r>0}(A_r|f|(x))$ where $A_r|f|(x)$ denotes the average value of function $|f|$ over $B(r,x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\chi_{\{a\}}$ *is* equal to zero! Because $L^1$ is actually a set of equivalence classes of functions up to almost-everywhere equality and $\chi_{\{a\}}$ is almost everywhere zero. We frequently commit the cardinal sin of abusing functions with their equivalence classes in $L^1$ but we should always have in mind what we are doing. A different way of saying the same thing is: $f$ is an integrable measurable function $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ and is *not* a.e. equal to zero. But $f\in L^1\setminus\{0\}$ is easier to say.

Comment: This makes so much more sense! Thank you. Completely slipped my mind that Folland refers towards $L^1$ as a set of equivalence classes.

Comment: @JAG131 As far as I know, everyone does (or should) use that definition of $L^1$. Otherwise, it is not a normed vector space so we can't do functional analysis on it or use metric space theory